# Why this below query returned no results?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-kubernetes-engine

SQL Query can be found on this link 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering#expandable-1-label

Even though there is no problem with Billing dataset & table as well as GKE usage metering dataset & table .

```
SELECT
  resource_usage.cluster_name,
  resource_usage.cluster_location,
  resource_usage.namespace,
  resource_usage.resource_name,
  resource_usage.sku_id,
  MIN(resource_usage.start_time) AS usage_start_time,
  MAX(resource_usage.end_time) AS usage_end_time,
  SUM(resource_usage.usage.amount * gcp_billing_export.rate) AS cost
FROM
  'cluster-gcp-project.usage-metering-dataset.gke_cluster_resource_usage' AS resource_usage
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    sku.id AS sku_id,
    SUM(cost) / SUM(usage.amount) AS rate,
    MIN(usage_start_time) AS min_usage_start_time,
    MAX(usage_end_time) AS max_usage_end_time
  FROM
    'cluster-gcp-project.billing-dataset.billing-table'
  WHERE
    project.id = "cluster-gcp-project"
  GROUP BY
    sku_id) AS gcp_billing_export
ON
  resource_usage.sku_id = gcp_billing_export.sku_id
WHERE
  resource_usage.start_time >= gcp_billing_export.min_usage_start_time
  AND resource_usage.end_time <= gcp_billing_export.max_usage_end_time
GROUP BY
  resource_usage.cluster_name,
  resource_usage.cluster_location,
  resource_usage.namespace,
  resource_usage.resource_name,
  resource_usage.sku_id
```

Comment: Could you please put the `SQL Query` you are talking about into the question.

Comment: I have added the SQL query

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, please provide some explanation for this logic

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an issue ,it is with the WHERE condition in that query

```
WHERE
  resource_usage.start_time >= gcp_billing_export.min_usage_start_time
  AND resource_usage.end_time <= gcp_billing_export.max_usage_end_time
```

As you could see below condition failed so that doesn't return any results .

FYI , Logic is to check & validate start_time and end_time of two different tables and return the values .

Thanks everyone for responding .